# Avoiding Error 429 Too Many Requests (Steam Web API)

Tags: javascript, rest, api, steam-web-api

I'm trying to make a site that displays information obtained from the Steam Web API but while testing, I received a 429 error. There is no indication for how long until I can make another request and its been over 3 hours. I've read that there is a 100,000 daily call limit but I didn't reach anywhere near that number.

The information I was trying to receive was the profiles of all my friends (around 100) to get their profile picture as well as the games I have recently played and their achievements. The information is called every time someone visits a web page and I was using a live server while working on the site (it made requests every time I saved and the browser reloaded). I'm guessing I might have made to many calls to quickly but is there a better design to approach what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

The 100,000 a day is from the [Steam API Terms and Conditions](https://steamcommunity.com/dev/apiterms) however, it seems that Steam estimates the rate over shorter periods. If you google around you'll see that many people limit the calls on a 5-minute bucket to around 200 per 5-minutes.

Certainly the way we do it is to define a bucket and every time a call is made, increment a counter. If the counter hits the limit for that bucket, we pause any new calls until the next bucket.

If you were making a call for the profile, played games and achievements for 100 people in a short period of time that may push it over the limit.

When a 429 is returned you may find [More information about when you can call next](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6585) in the headers.