# Steam crawler/scraper Python script that is not yielding all the information requested?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, web-crawler, steam

I am currently using a Steam-crawler (https://github.com/aesuli/steam-crawler) script that, based on a dataset with game IDs, is able to scrape Steam reviews data (date, text of the review, ID of the user, etc...). I am not an expert in HTML scraping, but from what I understood from the code (that is below), the script is looping for a given game ID to collect all reviews, until it encounters this specific situation `endre = re.compile(r'({"success":2})|(no_more_reviews)')`.

```
import argparse
import csv
import os
import re
import socket
import string
import urllib
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import json
from contextlib import closing
from time import sleep


def download_page(url, maxretries, timeout, pause):
    tries = 0
    htmlpage = None
    while tries < maxretries and htmlpage is None:
        try:
            with closing(urllib.request.urlopen(url, timeout=timeout)) as f:
                htmlpage = f.read()
                sleep(pause)
        except (urllib.error.URLError, socket.timeout, socket.error):
            tries += 1
    return htmlpage


def getgameids(filename):
    ids = set()
    with open(filename, encoding='utf8') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            dir = row[0] #à la base c'est 0
            id_ = row[1]
            name = row[2]
            ids.add((dir, id_, name))
    return ids


def getgamereviews(ids, timeout, maxretries, pause, out):
    urltemplate = string.Template(
        'https://store.steampowered.com//appreviews/$id?cursor=$cursor&filter=recent&language=english')
    endre = re.compile(r'({"success":2})|(no_more_reviews)')

    for (dir, id_, name) in ids:
        if dir == 'sub':
            print('skipping sub %s %s' % (id_, name))
            continue

        gamedir = os.path.join(out, 'pages', 'reviews', '-'.join((dir, id_)))

        donefilename = os.path.join(gamedir, 'reviews-done.txt') #When all reviews of a given have been extracted
        if not os.path.exists(gamedir):  #Create a folder if not existing
            os.makedirs(gamedir)
        elif os.path.exists(donefilename): #if folder exists, skip game
            print('skipping app %s %s' % (id_, name))
            continue

        print(dir, id_, name)

        cursor = '*'
        offset = 0
        page = 1
        maxError = 10
        errorCount = 0
        i = 0
        while True:
            url = urltemplate.substitute({'id': id_, 'cursor': cursor})
            print(offset, url)
            htmlpage = download_page(url, maxretries, timeout, pause)

            if htmlpage is None:
                print('Error downloading the URL: ' + url)
                sleep(pause * 3)
                errorCount += 1
                if errorCount >= maxError:
                    print('Max error!')
                    break
            else:
                with open(os.path.join(gamedir, 'reviews-%s.html' % page), 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
                    htmlpage = htmlpage.decode()
                    if endre.search(htmlpage):
                        break
                    f.write(htmlpage)
                    page = page + 1
                    parsed_json = (json.loads(htmlpage))
                    cursor = urllib.parse.quote(parsed_json['cursor'])

        with open(donefilename, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            pass


def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Crawler of Steam reviews')
    parser.add_argument('-f', '--force', help='Force download even if already successfully downloaded', required=False,
                        action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument(
        '-t', '--timeout', help='Timeout in seconds for http connections. Default: 180',
        required=False, type=int, default=180)
    parser.add_argument(
        '-r', '--maxretries', help='Max retries to download a file. Default: 5',
        required=False, type=int, default=3)
    parser.add_argument(
        '-p', '--pause', help='Seconds to wait between http requests. Default: 0.5', required=False, default=0.01,
        type=float)
    parser.add_argument(
        '-m', '--maxreviews', help='Maximum number of reviews per item to download. Default:unlimited', required=False,
        type=int, default=5000000)
    parser.add_argument(
        '-o', '--out', help='Output base path', required=False, default='data')
    parser.add_argument(
        '-i', '--ids', help='File with game ids', required=False, default='./data/games.csv')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    if not os.path.exists(args.out):
        os.makedirs(args.out)

    ids = getgameids(args.ids)

    print('%s games' % len(ids))

    getgamereviews(ids, args.timeout, args.maxretries, args.pause, args.out)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The issue that I am currently facing is that the script is not properly extracting correctly the reviews: for instance, for a game such as Counter-Strike Global Offensive that has about ~1,000,000 reviews, the script will sometimes return either 4000 pages of reviews (each html page contains 20 reviews), 6000 or 500 until it stops!

What I imagined as a solution was perhaps to save each URL that the script tested, and repeat the loop 10 times each time `endre = re.compile(r'({"success":2})|(no_more_reviews)')` is True, and to skip URL that have already been collected, however I'm not sure it would actually work?

I would also raise the issue on the GitHub page, but the author does not seem to often respond, and I am really interested on why it is happening, and if it is possible to solve this issue. Thank you in advance.

EDIT: So I looked a bit on the Steam API documentation https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/store/getreviews and it seems that each page gives a cursor as to be able to load the next page. So why is it randomly changing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Rate Limiting](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_limiting) is like a form of basic self-defense for a web server. Steam uses this to help keep it's servers from being abused (too much). Scraping 500+ full web pages is *a lot* of wasted bandwidth - let alone 4k+ pages - as much of the data from which is useless because the machine isn't running the JS or displaying anything anyways.

That last link you shared [seems to be an official endpoint](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/store/getreviews) to do this, but you will probably have to handle Status Code 429 ["Too Many Requests"](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/webapi_overview/responses) specially. [Related Q & A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51795457/7665043) that mentions this status *should* come with a `Retry-After` header and possibly a description of the limit. According to [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Retry-After) the value of Retry-After may be a date or the number of seconds to wait.

The `cursor` value is likely generated on the server side and just used to identify a chunk of 20 reviews, as that's the default "page size". The documentation says this is meant to be sent with the following request to get the next chunk of reviews from the list.